# C++ encoding macro

Tags: c++, character-encoding, macros

Is there a macro that tells you what encoding C++ is using for its wchar_t type?
I am currently stuck to GNU and clang. I am guessing UTF32 because my wchar_t has a size of 4 bytes. Although it could be UTF-16, it also uses 4 bytes for some code-points.

But then there is still the problem of UCS-4 or UTF-32LE or UTF-32BE.

Any help/expertise on this topic?

Comment: You don't have to worry about endianness unless you're trying to `memcpy` some random bytes into your `wchar_t` array.

Comment: UTF-16, by definition, uses 16-bit code points, i.e. 2 bytes (on most platforms).

Comment: @KennyTM UTF-16 uses 16 bits and 32 bits, there are well over 1 million characters defined in unicode, so the majority is encoded with two 16bit code units (although all the most used ones fit in one code unit). Maybe you're thinking about UCS2? Which is always limited to one 16 bit code unit?

Comment: @Pieter: What do you think surrogate pairs are for?

Answer (score 2):

wchar_t is implementation specific. It is not bound any specific encoding. If you are on a platform where wchar_t is 16 bits then it simply does not support UTF32 for example.

Encoding (UTF8, UTF32) and storage (wchar_t) are different things.

Comment: Well, it supports UTF32 with `uint32_t`, but it won't give you a prebuilt string type for it.  *However*, you *may* be able to make a subclass of `std::basic_string<>` that uses 32-bit storage...

Comment: Because wchar_t is implementation-specific, you cannot use it to write cross-platform (or even cross-implementation) code. To write cross-platform code, you either have to define your own type as Mike says, or stick to char / std::string and use UTF-8.

Comment: @Jon: No, that doesn't help. UTF-8 with std::string has basically the same portability problems as UTF-16 and std::wstring: you'll have to provide a lot of custom string functions. And note that I'm intentionally saying "UTF-16 and wchar_t". Yes, `wchar_t` may be 32 bits. So? `char` may be 16 bits, so `char` and UTF-8 is just as portable as `wchar_t` and UTF-16.

Comment: @MSalters: +1, I've never been on a system where char is 16 bits, so I didn't know that it was also implementation specific!

Comment: Check `CHAR_BIT` for that. You won't see this in desktop PCs. However, DSP's, small embedded controllers, GPUs, or big number crunching supercomputers might.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such macro in C++. In C99, there is macro [**STDC_ISO_10646**](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/iso2022-wc.html) to indicate that wchar_t is Unicode. In C++, encoding of characters stored in wchar_t depends on locale and it is implementation-defined feature. In other words, you need to consult documentation of the C++ implementation you use to see see what wchar_t is associated with each locale.